# app crashed due to exception NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json, exception

iam getting the data from the web service but it was crashed at URL request see the below code

```
- (void)loadDataSource  
 {

   // Request  
    NSString *URLPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://imgur.com/gallery.json"];  
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLPath];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

**CRASHED HERE**    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)  
 {

        NSInteger responseCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

        if (!error && responseCode == 200) {
            id res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
            if (res && [res isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                self.items = [res objectForKey:@"gallery"];
                [self dataSourceDidLoad];
            } else {
                [self dataSourceDidError];
            }
        } else {
            [self dataSourceDidError];
        }
    }];
}
```

please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, however there is no object for key @"gallery" in the result. Looks like the key is @"data". So change your code to

```
self.items = [res objectForKey:@"data"]
```